# Guzzle Request query params

Tags: php, guzzle

I have a method using gullzehttp and would like to change it to the pool plus the pool implements the Request method

```
<?php
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$params = ['password' => '123456'];
$header = ['Accept' => 'application/xml'];
$options = ['query' => $params, 'headers' => $header];
$response = $client->request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/get', $options);
```

I need to change to the Request method, but I could not find in the documentation how to send querystring variables in the Request

```
<?php
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
$request = new Request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/get', $options);
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to add the query as a string to the URI.

For that you can use [http_build_query](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) or a [guzzle helper function](https://github.com/guzzle/psr7#function-build_query) to convert a parameter array to an encoded query string:

```
$uri = new Uri('http://httpbin.org/get');

$request = new Request('GET', $uri->withQuery(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\build_query($params)));

// OR 

$request = new Request('GET', $uri->withQuery(http_build_query($params)));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Seems like their [6.5 Docs](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/6.5/quickstart.html#query-string-parameters) cause confusion making it seem you can add query parameters in the `$options` array.

Answer (score 1):

I also had trouble figuring out how to properly place the `new Request()` parameters. but structuring it the way i did below using php `http_build_query` to convert my arrays to query params and then appended it to the url before sending fixed it.

```
try {

        // Build a client
        $client = new Client([
            // Base URI is used with relative requests
            'base_uri' => 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com',
            // You can set any number of default request options.
            // 'timeout'  => 2.0,
        ]);

        // Prepare a request
        $url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest';
        $headers = [
            'Accepts' => 'application/json',
            'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY' => '05-88df-6f98ba'
        ];
        $params = [
            'id' => '1'
        ];
        $request = new Request('GET', $url.'?'.http_build_query($params), $headers);

        // Send a request
        $response = $client->send($request);

        // Receive a response
        dd($response->getBody()->getContents());
        return $response->getBody()->getContents();

    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        dd('did not work', $th);
        return false;
    }
```